# Laravel Retrieve Parameter to function view

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

Laravel 7: I'm building a report view using Maathwebsite.
My function looks like this.

```
public function view(): View
   {
      return view('dash._exportSales' ['datas' => Sales::where('store_id', 30)->get()]);
   }
```

This will output an excel file with all the information, as you can see I'm using a basic settings, so far so good, the problem that I have is that I have no idea how to give a parameter, the number 30 is the ID but how can I retrieve that number?
my route looks like this

```
Route::get('sales/export_sales', 'SaleController@export')->name('export.sales');
```

if I use: `Route::get('lots/export_sales/{id}', 'SaleController@export')->name('export.sales');`
doesn't do anything still can't get the ID in to my `ExportController` which looks like this:

```
class SaleExport implements FromView
{


 public function view(): View
       {
          return view('dash._exportSales' ['datas' => Sales::where('store_id', 30)->get()]);
       }
}
```

If add a declare a private, const, public or protected variable it does nothing nor can set or retrieve a value... 
So how can I retrieve that ID #?

Export is on my SalesController.php, the above class is on my SalesExport.php

SalesExport looks like this:

```
  public function export($id)
   {
      
      $name = 'store_' . $id . '.xlsx';
      return Excel::download(new SaleExport(), $name);
   }
```

My routes looks like this.

```
Route::get('sales/export_sales/{id}', SaleController@export')->name('export.sales');
Route::get('sales', 'SaleController@sales')->name('sales');
```

Comment: please share export() method

Comment: @Ranjeet, I have added... thank you for taking the time, much appreciated.

Comment: if only classes had constructors

Comment: Damm you @lagbox, lmao!... sometimes I got stuck with the problem and never look the whole picture... Thank you!

Comment: hehe no problem, good luck :)

Comment: you can put an answer up for other people's benefit if you wish

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by following way

```
Route::get('sales/export_sales/{id}', 'SaleController@export')->name('export.sales');
```

and your method should be like this

```
public function view($id)
           {
              return view('dash._exportSales' ['datas' => Sales::where('store_id', $id)->get()]);
           }
```

Comment: I did that before asking, actually it is on my question..., it returns something like: 1 parameter sent, but method doesn't use any... but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The whole problem was that I never use __construct() on my controller.
So, here is the full flow
**Laravel 7**+
**maatwebsite/excel**
First the view:

```
<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="4">Report {{ date('Y-m-d H:i:s') }} | Store: {{ $datas->store_name }}</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th style="font-weight: bold; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">Sale #</th>
    <th style="font-weight: bold; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">Amount</th>
    <th style="font-weight: bold; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">Date</th>
    <th style="font-weight: bold; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;"></th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  @foreach($datas->items as $data)
    <tr>
      <td>{{ $data->id }}</td>
      <td>{{ $data->amount }}</td>
      <td>{{ $data->date }}</td>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  @endforeach
  </tbody>
</table>
```

It has more columns but lets keep it simple.
in app create a new folder app/Exports, inside SaleExport.php
Inside that file use it like this:

```
namespace App\Exports;

use App\Sale;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromView;
//use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class SaleExport implements FromView
{

   protected $id;

   public function __construct($id)
   {
      $this->id = $id;
   }

   public function view(): View
   {
      return view('dash._exportsales', ['datas' => Sales::where('store_id', $this->id)->get()]);
   }
}
```

On this file was the problem there was no `__contruct();` but I didn't notice because it was been called from another controller with `__construct();` so my "view controller looks like this.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Dash;

use App\Order;
use App\Sale;
//use Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Exports\SaleExport;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class ReportController extends Controller 
{

   public function index(Request $resquest)
   {
     // This is just a basic index nothing fancy
     // I could avoid this 'where' but client only want this status...
      $query = Order::where('status', 1);
      // a few IF's to build query with orWhere();, limit();... etc
      // here is where I could add the 'status' and set it as filter...
      $data = $query->paginate($limit);
      return view('dash.order_list', compact('data');
   }

   // Here is where we call our Export

public function export($id)
   {  
      $name = 'sales_' . $id . '.xlsx'; // Set the same for the file
      return Excel::download(new SaleExport($id), $name);
   }
}
```

Then you can just called in your router `Route::get('sales', 'SaleController@export')->name('sales');` and thats it!, you get a full report using a blade view in to your excel software... problem was is that I wasn't using `__construct();` on my FromView controller
Reference about this method can be found here: [docs.laravel-excel](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.0/exports/from-view.html), problem on my part was that the construct, without a construct can't use parameters, now that is been set I can use parameters and do more filters for a better report.
Thanks to @lagbox who reminded me of that.